Gradle project keeps disappearing every time I switch tabs on IntelliJ
I am facing an Issue with my intelliJ. Every time I switch tab on my Mac, my gradle project disappears and I have to Reload all Gradle projects again to make it appear again.
I have tried disabling plugins but It doesn't work

Check the "On frame deactivation" option in your Run Configurations. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html)
Also, make sure the "Reload project after changes in the build scripts" option is set to "External changes", try temporarily disabling the option (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-build-tools.html)
